# How to copy files stored in variables by stutils

Tags: python, variables, file-handling

I want to change the extension of a file which is taken as a user generated input(raw_input) but I need to keep the original file the same and so this program copies the content from original file to output file.

This is a part of my program that aims to do the same -

```
var = raw_input("Enterfile ")
fid = open(var)
import os
name, extension = os.path.splitext(var)
path = os.path.abspath(var)
outputfile = os.path.splitext(var)[0]+ '.asd'
print path
print var
print outputfile
fo = open(outputfile, 'w')
import shutil
shutil.copyfile(var, fo)
data = fo.read()
print data
```

The error returned -

```
File "p.py", line 18, in <module>
    shutil.copyfile(var, fo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 68, in copyfile
    if _samefile(src, dst):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 58, in _samefile
    return os.path.samefile(src, dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 154, in samefile
    s2 = os.stat(f2)
```

I am not sure what is wrong with my program,please help. Also is there more efficient way of doing this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error seems incomplete.

Comment: @Jermaine Xu I have copied the whole error message from the terminal.

Comment: also, you are trying to read from a file that is only opened for writing to.

Comment: @monkut I have tried using both 'r' and 'w' mode regardless of the mode same error pops up both the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `shutil.copyfile` works with file *names*, not file *descriptors*.  You don't need to open the files, and you definitely don't want to pass file objects to the copyfile method.

The code should look something more like this: (and be sure to check http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html if you are unsure about the parameter types)

```
import os.path
import shutil

input_filename = raw_input("Enterfile ")
base_name, extension = os.path.splitext(input_filename)
output_filename = base_name + '.asd'

shutil.copyfile(input_filename, output_filename)
```

Comment: That does solve the problem but I think I did not make myself clear in the question, I need to open the file as my program requires me to do the same and I need to be able to read line from the output file which are later used in the program.

Comment: You can still open the files before or after the copying, but if you are going to use `shutil.copyfile`, you must pass filename strings to it.